# AdMod ads on different pages / different languages

Tags: android, admob

Is it possible to set different AdMob language filters for different pages displaying different languages within the same android app ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new "app" in admob for each language, and under the language settings turn off all of the languages except for the one you want for that ID.

Next, for the layout of each page, use the unique app ID for that language when you insert the XML for the ad.

The thing to test, however, is if that affects your fill rate if there aren't language-specific ads in your region for that language.